# How to search for strings that contain double quotes?

Tags: support, search

I'm having a problem with Excel concerning the way Excel optimizes spreadsheets by sharing common formulas that appear in multiple cells.  When Excel does this, it places `t="shared"` within a formula element that occurs within a cell element.

I stumbled upon a question regarding this in SO and the question's title contained the string `t="shared"`.  I thought it would be good idea to search for all SO questions that contained the string `t="shared"` but discovered that there's no way to search for that.  I even tried `"t="shared""` hoping that that might work, but no luck.

Is this search string unsearchable in SO?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: This problem is quite common, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+symbol) is a list of questions that might help you.

Comment: I think it's a problem if you can't search for a string that occurs in a question, but somehow I feel it's a bigger problem if you can't search for a string that occurs within the question's title.

Comment: Anyone else click through to this question thinking that it was mis-posted because the asker was question banned on StackOverflow?

Comment: It's very hard to search for titles with quotes in them.  I've asked about this on meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202612/how-can-i-search-for-questions-with-the-error-message-application-not-a-proced.

Comment: Hi, have you tried `"t=""shared"""`? on `VBA` it's works.

Comment: @RafaBG `"t=""shared"""` does not find occurrences of `t="shared"` on StackOverflow, which was the stated question.  I'm not certain what you mean when you mention `VBA` (I can only think of Visual Basic for Applications).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a pretty specific thing to search for. I don't know if `t="shared"` means something special in Excel or if it's a common idiom but that sounds hard to search for regardless of the capabilities of the engine.

You could try using the `*` wildcard, like `"t*shared"`. This gave me two relevant results where `t="shared"` was matched exactly.

Comment: While I think the search capabilities in SO could be better, that's a pretty good workaround.

Comment: @mbmast [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=t%3D%22shared%22) returned different results than [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22t*shared%22). So I would use both.

Comment: Nice site.  I'll be adding that to my set of bookmarks.